# How to apply where clause for criteria fetch mode?

Tags: hibernate

I am working with Hibernate ,I have tables User & Address with one to many relationship.
please check my code below

```
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    crit.setFetchMode("address", FetchMode.JOIN);
   // crit.add(Restrictions.eq("address.city", "new Street"));
    crit.setResultTransformer(crit.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    List<User> userList = crit.list();
```

This is working fine.**But In my address table I have City column ,here I want to apply where clause for address ( where address.city=vizag) how can I do this any one help me.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807707/how-to-select-nested-property-using-hibernate-criteria

Comment: Thanks for the replay ,But createAlias work like InnerJoin.So I have one user with two address at that time I got two rows .But I want only one row

Comment: crit.setResultTransformer(crit.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);  should prevent that, jrr jrr