# Transient property causes org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: severidadeRecente of: br.com.timbrasil.bluemonster.modelo.Csr

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, transient

I'm trying to use Criteria API to get a `List<Csr>` ordered by its transient `severidadeRecente` property.

The entity and the relationship i'm using:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "csr")
public class Csr implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "csr")
    private List<CsrSeveridadeLog> severidadeLogList;

    //Used to get and set the most recent Severidade
    @Transient
    private CsrSeveridadeLog severidadeRecente;

    public CsrSeveridadeLog getSeveridadeRecente() {
        Calendar compare = null;
        CsrSeveridadeLog recente = null;

        for (CsrSeveridadeLog log : severidadeLogList) {
            if (compare == null) {
                compare = log.getData();
                recente = log;
            }
            if (log.getData().after(compare)) {
                recente = log;
            }
        }
        return recente;
    }
```

I'm using the below criteria query:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Csr.class,"csr");
if ("severidadeRecente".equals(filtro.getPropriedadeOrdenacao())) {
    criteria.createAlias("csr.severidadeRecente", "severidadeRecente");
}
```

The `filtro.getPropriedadeOrdenacao()` is coming from the client.

But I get the following exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: severidadeRecente of: br.com.timbrasil.bluemonster.modelo.Csr

How can I solve it? I need to order my table based on a `List` that my entity has, taking the most recent record on that list.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @kavain i had to change my approach, but the answer of szarpul is correct.
I had to stoped using the List<CsrSeveridadeLog> and use a CsrSeveridadeLog inside the Csr class, so that way i was able to use the order by.
Hope it helps

Comment: Would you mind to check my question about a similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598960/how-to-make-a-criteria-with-select-order-by-avg-function-in-a-one-to-many-re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have filed `severidadeRecente` in `Csr` class with proper getter and setter?

**UPDATE:**

As @ChssPly76 [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722539/java-hibernate-could-not-resolve-property-with-nested-object-criterias#1723851):

> You can't use nested paths directly in Criteria API (unlike HQL).
>   Instead, you need to create nested criteria instances or define
>   aliases on each "entity.property" pair starting with the first
>   non-root entity

So try to do something like this:

```
criteria.createAlias("csr", "c")
.createAlias("c.severidadeRecente", "severidadeRecente")
```

Comment: Yes, I have the field severidadeRecente  marked with @Transient, the getter is on the question, on the moment of the order it is filed.

Comment: The same result.
I update my question, i was omitting the criteria creation:
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Csr.class,"csr");
Either doing csr.severidadeRecente or giving a new alias to csr are the same,no?