# Using Hibernate Criteria API, how to query for a subproperty of a property that exists only for certain property types

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

Consider classes `Account`, `RealAccount`, `VirtualAccount`, and `Operation` such that:

```
class Account { }
class RealAccount extends Account { String name; }
class VirtualAccount extends Account { }
class Operation { Account account; }
```

This means that:

1. Only `RealAccount` has a field called `name`.
2. `Operation`'s account can be `RealAccount` or `VirtualAccount`.

I want to query for all `Operation`s that belong to a `RealAccount` with a specific name:

```
session.createCriteria(Operation.class)
   .createAlias("account", "_account")
   .add(Restrictions.eq("_account.name", "Alice"))
   .list();
```

This fails.

My question: Using the **"old" Hibernate Criteria API**, how can I query for the **account name** that exists only when the `Operation`'s account is a `RealAccount`? Maybe something envolving `DetachedCriteria` and `Subqueries`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java / Hibernate: Could not resolve property with nested object criterias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722539/java-hibernate-could-not-resolve-property-with-nested-object-criterias)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference `name` on `RealAccount` in a subquery (below example uses HQL, but a [Criteria equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637204/4754790) should be straightforward):

```
select op from Operation op
where op.account.id in
  (select id from RealAccount where name = :name)
```

Comment: That's not Criteria API.